# Addrange Inaccessible due to protection level?

Tags: c#, mono

At somewhere cb.Items.AddRange(databases) there is inaccessibility due to protection level but all variables were set to public.
Here it says:

> C:\Users\Shulz\Documents\MySql\Oliver exer3\showdb.cs(77,18): error
>   CS0122: `Sys
>   tem.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(System.Collections.IList)'
>   is inaccessible due to its protection level
>   C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-3~1.3\lib\mono\4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll (Location
>   of the sy mbol related to previous error) Compilation failed: 1
>   error(s), 0 warnings

```
    public ComboBox cb;
    public Label label;
    public object[] databases;

    public MForm() {

       string connectionString =
          "Server=localhost;" +
          "Database=information_schema;" +
          "User ID=root;" +
          "Password=root;" +
          "Pooling=false";
       IDbConnection dbcon;
       dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
       dbcon.Open();
       IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA"; //count the databases(string) and names it count
        dbcmd.CommandText = sql;                        //sends the string to sql
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();     //assign the function to reader
        reader.Read();                                  //uses its getter(Read)
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["count"]);   //converts the "count"(column) to integer

        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;



        dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        sql = "show databases";
        dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
        reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

        var databases = new List<string>();

        var excludeDatabases = new List<string> { "information_schema","sakila","enrollmentsystem","mysql","world","performance_schema" };

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            var data = reader["Database"].ToString();

            if(!excludeDatabases.Contains(data)){
            databases.Add(data);
            }
        }

       reader.Close();
       reader = null;
       dbcmd.Dispose();
       dbcmd = null;
       dbcon.Close();
       dbcon = null;




        Text = "School Year";
        Size = new Size(340, 240);

        cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.Parent = this;
        cb.Location = new Point(50, 30);

        cb.Items.AddRange(databases);

        cb.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(OnChanged);

        label = new Label();
        label.Location = new Point(80, 170);
        label.Parent = this;
        label.Text = "...";

        CenterToScreen();




    }

    void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         ComboBox combo = (ComboBox) sender;
         label.Text = combo.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Mono. Looking at your error message I can say that you items is perhaps read-only or private property of combo box. There may be other way to set up data source for combobox like here : combobox.DataSource = YourData;

Comment: You're passing in a `List<T>` but the method expects an `object[]`.

Comment: Yes. I am Using a mono compiler. So how can I convert this to object[] ?

Answer (score 1):

A `List<string>` is not an `object[]`, so it's not compatible with `AddRange` and you get a compiler error.

On .net this error is:

> The best overloaded method match for `'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])'` has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'` to `'object[]'`

Mono seems to have another internal overload taking an `IList`. If this overload were accessible, it'd match your call. So the suggested cause for the error is a bit different.

In general the compiler first notices that there is no matching overload. To help you, it tries to guess at the likely cause. This guess can be affected by the presence of internal methods.

Comment: What does interneal overload mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to solve this problem. So what I did is db.ToArray() then assinged my databases which is object. It was just simple as that.

```
    var db = new List<string>();

    var excludeDatabases = new List<string> { "information_schema","sakila","enrollmentsystem","mysql","world","performance_schema" };

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        var data = reader["Database"].ToString();

        if(!excludeDatabases.Contains(data)){
        db.Add(data);

        }
    }

   reader.Close();
   reader = null;
   dbcmd.Dispose();
   dbcmd = null;
   dbcon.Close();
   dbcon = null;




    Text = "School Year";
    Size = new Size(340, 240);

    cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.Parent = this;
    cb.Location = new Point(50, 30);


    databases = db.ToArray();
    cb.Items.AddRange(databases);
```